# Unable to handle kernel paging request for data at address XXXXXX

Tags: memory, kernel, paging

Now I am doing some Linux kernel debug. I modified the CFS task scheduling part. Generally every time the function schedule() is called, I try to store or access all the existing sched_entity( similiar  to task_struct conceptually) using pointers. Then the kernel crashes with the error 
"
Unable to handle kernel paging request  for data at address XXXXXX
"
Does this mean the kernel do not have access to all the task information? The kernel only has access to the task who calls the schedule() function? Just like in the user space, different process have different memory space.
I am rookie in the kernel programming so I appreciate if anyone can give me a hint:>
Thanks,

Comment: Does this occur when you try to write to that memory or just read from it? Some of the memory areas in the kernel space can be write-protected but I am not sure about this one.

Comment: Could you show the relevant portions of your code and of the kernel oops message? It would make it much easier for the kernel experts to help you here. Generally, "unable to handle paging request" errors may arise due to different reasons, it is diffucult to tell what the problem is without seeing the code.